# Is it possible to create a Proxy in WSO2 ESB that exposes a single operation?

Tags: proxy, wso2-esb

We have an existing web service that has 4 operations on it.  We have a new project where we would like to proxy this service on WSO2 ESB.  Rather than proxying the whole service contract is it possible to create a proxy for a single operation?

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom WSDL and create a WSDL based Proxy (i.e. take the backend WSDL and remove the operations you don't want). Alternatively you can use something like a switch / filter mediator to route to back end based on requests received.